# SQL Server: Ordering rows before select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Can't quite get my head around this one.  I need to select all the records where an order was placed before the supplies ran out. For instance if someone orders a 30 day supply on 1/1/2014 and then orders another 30 days supply before 25% of the supply is used it is considered a duplicate order.  What I have now is a nested select:

```
USE petsnmore
  SELECT * 
      INTO duplicates_2014
      FROM orders a
      WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT * 
             FROM orders b
             WHERE a.ID!=b.ID AND
                   a.claim_num = b.claim_num AND
                   a.service_id = b.service_id AND
                   a.visit_num = b.visit_num AND
                   b.dos BETWEEN a.dos AND DateAdd(dd,FLOOR(a.days_supply*.25),a.dos) 
         )
```

The returned rows are not what is expected and the reason I think is because the rows are not compared in proper order.   I think it needs:

```
        Order by claim_num ASC, service_id ASC, dos ASC, visit_num DESC
```

Of course SQL Server only allows ORDER by on the outside select.   I know there has got to be a better way.   Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Can you also elaborate on *"the returned rows are not what is expected"*, we do not know what you are expecting, or what is actually being returned, so cannot possibly tell you why there is a difference.

Comment: Yes, it is usually done using window functions (`ROW_NUMBER`, `LAG`, `LEAD`). Exactly which and how, pls edit the question to show us some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Why do you add the 25% of the days_supply to a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a table variable (or a temp table if you want to query your results more than once) to order your data and then use that table to join back to your original query and see where you can go from there.

```
declare @duplicateorders table (<fields from orders table>)
SELECT * into @duplicateorders
         FROM orders b
         WHERE a.ID!=b.ID AND
               a.claim_num = b.claim_num AND
               a.service_id = b.service_id AND
               a.visit_num = b.visit_num AND
               b.dos BETWEEN a.dos AND DateAdd(dd,FLOOR(a.days_supply*.25),a.dos)
         ORDER BY claim_num ASC, service_id ASC, dos ASC, visit_num DESC
```

Comment: I tried this first and it seems to be producing the results I need.  It's a billion row table, so it took awhile to get the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE (either doing the ordering "near" the CTE or at the end when you insert:

```
;WITH (myCTE)
 AS
 (
  SELECT * 
  FROM orders a
  WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT * 
         FROM orders b
         WHERE a.ID!=b.ID AND
               a.claim_num = b.claim_num AND
               a.service_id = b.service_id AND
               a.visit_num = b.visit_num AND
               b.dos BETWEEN a.dos AND DateAdd(dd,FLOOR(a.days_supply*.25),a.dos) 
     )
  )
  Select
        *
  INTO 
        duplicates_2014
  from
        myCTE
```